# Passing Function With Parameters in Context in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I have Function With Parameters in Context File and the Parameters need to pass it onClick, But it's show error "onLogin is not a function"

**Context.js**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext(undefined);

export default Context({children}) {
    const CheckUser = (Username, Password) => {
        const Data = {
            email: Username,
            password: Password
        }
        API.post('/login', Data)
            .then( response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.log(error.message);
            })
    }

    <AuthContext.Provider value={{onLogin: CheckUser}}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

**Child.js**

```
const onLogin = useContext(Context);
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

<form>
     <TextField onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
     <TextField onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
     <Button onClick={() => onLogin(username, password)}>Login</Button>
</form>
```

Comment: In Childs.js Context is AuthContext ?

Comment: Cilds.js it's deep on off {childeren} components

Comment: Yes, but you need to have the reference to AuthContext in order to invoke the context.
te right syntax should be `const onLogin = useContext(AuthContext); `

Comment: I make Update on Question to full code i have